# how to get the objective function value of model train with the class sklearn.svm?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

How can I get the objective function value of svm model? I'm using the python library `sklearn` which contains the class `sklearn.svm.SVC`, and I don't know how to return the objective function value.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please only use english text here. I've removed the french duplicate, because this site's policy is to have all text in english. I understand the good intentions, but the idea here is to not be redundant and be universally understandable.

Comment: Ok it's not a problem, i just want to have the answer

Comment: Probably I cannot help you with an answer. I know Python well, but  scikit not at all. Maybe you can elaborate a bit in your question what you mean with "return the objective function value". It is unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Usually questions get more attention if they show your own research, what you have tried, what went wrong. Possibly some code examples and an error message. See the `help` link at the top of the page for more info on how to ask good questions and how the site works.

Comment: when we run this class with option verbose=1 ie: "clf = svm.SVC(verbose=1)
p = ""+clf.fit(X, y)"  we have in terminal an output which contain the objective like "obj= -0.2548" for example, but i don't kown how to get this obj value in a program.

Comment: You might want to edit your own question and add this additional information. Also do you realize how the printout happens? How exactly does your Python script look like (try to reduce to the shortest testcase reproducing the issue) and how do you run it?

Comment: i have seen the obj variable's value, but i don't know how to get it in my code.